# close csv files in loop

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I would like to open many csv files from the same folder, copy the data to 'collectdatahere.xlsm' then close the csv file and open the next one.

I receive error message `Subscript out of range` even though I opened the file the same way:

```
Sub osszefuz()
    Dim Folder As String
    Dim File As String
    Dim wbname As String

    Sheets("Munka1").Range("A2").Select
    Folder = "Z:\project\path"
    File = Dir(Folder & "\*.csv")

    Do While File <> ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Folder & "\" & File, Local:=True
        wbname = Folder & "\" & File
        Range("A2", Range("E2").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        Workbooks("collectdatahere.xlsm").Activate
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
        Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
        **Workbooks(wbname).Close savechanges:=False**
        File = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: `File = Dir(Folder & "\*.csv")`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `SELECT`; try this code, see if it does what you want:

```
Sub CopyAllCSV()
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim wsPaste As Worksheet
    Const sFolder As String = "Z:\project\path"
    Set wsPaste = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Munka1")
    sFile = Dir(sFolder & "\*.csv")

    Do While sFile <> ""
        With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFolder & "\" & sFile, Local:=True)
            With .Worksheets(1)
                .Range("A2", .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            End With
            wsPaste.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
            .Close savechanges:=False
        End With
        sFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Then you may consider upvoting and marking as your answer. Thanks.

Comment: I did but I'm noob here :/

Comment: That's ok - even noobs can [mark their questions as answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)